# PayPal REST API - Coupon / Discount Code (Negative Numbers)

Tags: paypal

I've been unable to find an accurate answer for this.

As we know already, PayPal's REST API doesn't have a option for applying discount code.  However, we can append another item to the item_list with a description of a I.e. Promo / Discount code.

So e.g. breaking this into human readable data, here's what I'm passing to the API.

**Transaction**

```
Amount: 100
item_list: [ product1, 60 ], [ product2, 60 ], [ coupon_code, -20 ]
```

Visually, This route should work (as it does in the classic API).  However, the **PayPal API doesn't allow negative numbers**.

Ideally, we want to use the signed / OAuth route via PayPal REST API Vs. the open / classic API.

---

**Update 1/13/2014**
I noticed Storenvy has the ability to apply discounts to their connected user's PayPal accounts.  However, If I recall Storenvy has a partnership with PayPal - I'm wondering if they're on a specific internal rest API version for the discount support?

Comment: If it's simply not allowing the negative number all you can do is notify them and hope enough people complain that they either fix it or finally give us an actual discount field to work with.  Until then you may have to stick with the classic API and adding it as a line-item with negative value like you explained.  That's why I haven't moved to REST yet.  Still too many things like this coming up when I try to build solutions for people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do it creating another item, and giving a negative price.

```
  $item = new Item();
  $price = -11.20;
  ......
  $item->setName($name)
        ->setCurrency($currency)
        ->setQuantity($quantity)
        ->setSku($sku)
        ->setPrice($price);
```

For this example I have a Promo code of -11.20 euro:

[image: promo code]

Comment: Using paypal is a headache for sure, think I'm gonna use stripe instead.

Comment: paypal is a nightmare: nowerdays negative numbers are not alowed

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

Add a `discount` field to the `breakdown`:

```php
'discount' => [
    'currency_code' => $order->currency,
    'value' => $order->coupon_total,
]
```

See PayPal's docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown

The discount will the show up as **discount** in the price breakdown.

Comment: Thanks @yiddidhe-kop, had the same issue and your solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Make negative value of coupon discount amount. It worked for me.

```
$itemArray = array();

    if (isset($request->couponId)) {

        // coupon object
        $coupon = (new Promocodes())->check($request->couponId);
    
        if (isset($coupon->code)) {
           $item = new Item();
           $item->setName('Coupon Discount')
                ->setCurrency('GBP')
                ->setQuantity(1)
                ->setPrice(($coupon->reward * (-1)));
    
           // to reduce reward amount from total
           $totalAmount -= $coupon->reward;
           array_push($itemArray, $item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

For discount we do have the discount variables `discount_amount` and `discount_percentage` where you can get:

> The amount and currency of the discount applied to the payment.

See the reference https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/ and search for the term "discount" there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Was this recently added? @Aaron

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without using Paypal invoicing? I am passing an `item_list` (as part of a `transaction`) as part of a payment.  I'm not using paypal invoicing, and I do not want to.  How can I add discounts to a payment/transaction?

Comment: You can now add an item with a negative amount as one workaround.  See this thread: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/55

Comment: There is no such discount variable in the REST API. Downvoted.

Comment: The discount_amount and discount_percentage variable are only available under installment_amount. They are not available for usual transactions. Not sure why this answer is marked as correct answer. Downvoted