# creating coupon in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

In stripe we can create coupon in the screen below for online payment, is there a corresponding way of doing that in paypal?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PayPal REST API - Coupon / Discount Code (Negative Numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710639/paypal-rest-api-coupon-discount-code-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Coupons are not implemented within PayPal itself.

You can create a payment with a discount applied, if you wish. Details are in the v2/checkout/orders API reference for creating an order.

Any coupon code that might exist and apply a discount, needs to be created and managed by you. PayPal is only interested in processing the final payment, for whatever amount you indicate when creating the order.